# THREE.js smooth axis rotation via mouse and THREE.Quaternion

Tags: javascript, animation, vector, rotation, three.js

I tried to build a smooth rotation for THREE.Object3D via mousemove - without any jitter, gaps, interruption or something else...
here is an isolated jsfiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vYvmk/

I am not getting it - tried several different scenarios via nested groups etc.
i guess Quaternion will do the trick but something went wrong...

Comment: http://pv3d.org/2008/12/28/click-then-tween-camera-to-plane/ slerp to plane -- as3 maybe some useful ressorce

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what's going wrong?

Comment: when i use mouse coordinates as vector - the rotation is gettin wild... i  think the rotation should be done from the origin? Im not getting into it. I will check the link above.

Comment: tried:
var time = Date.now() * .0025;
var va = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix( mesh.matrix );
var vb = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler( vector );//( vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, 1 );
var vc = new THREE.Quaternion();
THREE.Quaternion.slerp( va, vb, vc, time );
//mesh.quaternion = vc;
mesh.quaternion.multiplySelf( vc );
mesh.quaternion.normalize();

Comment: Okay im gettin closer - but this looks more like mesh.lookAt( mouse3D )?! the mesh should spin continuously...
var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler( vector );
    var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    THREE.Quaternion.slerp( mesh.quaternion, q, newQuaternion, 0.07 );
    mesh.quaternion = newQuaternion;
    mesh.quaternion.normalize();

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but my slerp-solution looks exakt like mesh.lookAt( mouse3D )?!
The mesh should spin continuously around target axis... 
Im not sure but mesh.quaternion.multiplySelf should be the trick - from here i have problems again =|

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2D.y, -mouse2D.x, 0 );//.normalize();
var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler( v );
var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
THREE.Quaternion.slerp( mesh.quaternion, q, newQuaternion, 0.07 );
mesh.quaternion = newQuaternion;
// mesh.quaternion.multiplySelf( newQuaternion );
mesh.quaternion.normalize();
```

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLta8/

Comment: You are using the POSITION in place of ROTATION - `.setFromEuler(v)` takes the ROTATION vector as a parameter, while you are feeding it with `new THREE.Vector3(mouse2D.y, -mouse2D.x, 0)`. It wont work. You'll have to compute the angle between the object's position and the cursor's one and then use it there.

Comment: Not fully working for me, but good attempt at least.

Answer (score 1):

I've just published a post on rotating an object  that may be similar to what you're looking for: Smooth Mouse Rotation in Three.js

Comment: sorry, here is the link for the above: http://benchung.com/smooth-mouse-rotation-three-js/

Comment: I found that post and it's awesome.  I've been trying to manipulate it to set an initial angle that is not 0 0 0, and running into problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282722/convert-three-js-rotation-to-aframe-in-component can you help with that?